# Package in unique jar with bouncyCastle.SecurityException

Tags: java, digital-signature, bouncycastle, build.xml

I created a Java UI with NetBeans and I need to include external jar and package it in only one jar.

I got the following error:

> Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again Exception in thread "main" java.lang.SecurityException: Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes

I changed the `build.xml` with the following code:

```
<target name="-post-jar">
    <jar jarfile="${dist.jar}" update="true">
        <zipgroupfileset dir="\Users\feli\Documents\bouncy\" excludes="META-INF/*.SF,META-INF/*.DSA,META-INF/*.RSA"/>
            <manifest>
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="herramientascriptograficas.AplicacionCriptografica"/>
        </manifest>
    </jar>
</target>
```

But, I got the same result.

I check the jar and I have in META-INF:

```
META-INF feli$ ls BC1024KE.DSA BC1024KE_1.DSA BC2048KE.DSA BC2048KE_1.DSA MANIFEST.MF BC1024KE.SF BC1024KE_1.SF BC2048KE.SF BC2048KE_1.SF
```

In conclusion, the `build.xml` doesn't exclude the files. Could you help me?

Ps: I have a Mac and I tried to change `excludes ="META-INF/**/*"`, and I got the same result

Answer (score 3):

Bouncycastle jars are signed because  [implements a cryptographic provider](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/HowToImplAProvider.html#Step6)

> If your provider is supplying encryption algorithms through the `Cipher` `KeyAgreement`, `KeyGenerator`, `Mac`, or `SecretKeyFactory` classes, you will need to sign your JAR file so that the JCA can authenticate the code at runtime.

You have repackaged all classes into a single jar, but you have not signed it. You are using the signature files of  bouncycastle's jars, but they are not valid now because you have changed the content

Options:

- Sign your code with a code signing certificate
- Deploy also bcprov-jdk15on-1.xx.jar with your app

Comment: Thanks, I deploy my application with bcprov-ext-jdk15on-158.jar bcprov-jdk15on-158.jar, in the path \Users\feli\Documents\bouncy\. In other hand, How could I sign my code with a code signing certificate? Thanks

Comment: In the link I posted you will find the steps to sign the jar. You will need a code signing certificate ( and probably pay for it). The simplest solution is pack all your packages in one jar except bouncycastle and distribute them separately